# React Native how to change iOS bundle identifier?

Tags: xcode, react-native, bundle-identifier

I tried to change the bundle identifier in the Info.plist and the xcode itself. (in full empty project).
But for some reason I can't build it. `Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist`. And what strange is that I can build it successfully in the xcode but not with the npm run ios. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the **react-native-rename** npm package.

```
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

On the root of your React Native project execute the following command

```
react-native-rename "ExampleApp" -b com.newname.newid
```

Check the docs > [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)